# Drupal: Store 'default theme' in Feature

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-themes

I'm afraid my question is a no-brainer for almost everybody, but I can't find the answer. I can't find it using Google, StackOverflow or by examaning the code generated by Features.

**How can I store the default theme of a site in a feature? Do I need Strongarm? What would be the name of the variable?**

(It feels like a duplicate of [Drupal Features include Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024423/drupal-features-include-theme), but we're four years further now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the actual theme, templates and all, then no. Features is only really intended for bundling configuration. If you just mean the setting for the default theme, yes: install Strongarm and select the `theme_default` variable when you're creating your Feature.

Comment: Indeed, I mean the latter. The variable seems not to be available in Strongarm. However, the variable is set in the installation profile and setting it in a Feature would override it (which is exactly what I want). Could it be that this variable is not available because of it being set in the profile?